# Select a element that contains two span text

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<label class=‘Fruit’>
  <span class=‘name’>Apple</span>
  <span class=‘price’>23</span>
</label>
<label class=‘Fruit’>
  <span class=‘name’>Apple</span>
  <span class=‘price’>56</span>
</label>
```

I am writing the automation script using `Selenium`. Currently, I am facing a problem in writing `xPath` to select the first label. However, these two label have same class name and the class name of its span is also the same. Only the price is different. In this situation, how can I select the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match numbers like below,

- To select the first element:  `//label[@class='‘Fruit’'][1]`
- To select the second  element:  `//label[@class='‘Fruit’'][2]`

You need to write a customized `xPath` when you need to select the `label` based on `Fruit name` and `Price`

**To select the first label**:

```
//label//span[text()='Apple']//following-sibling::span[text()='23']//parent::label
```

or

```
//label//span[@class='‘name’' and text()='Apple']//following-sibling::span[@class='‘price’' and text()='23']//parent::label
```

**To select the second label**:

```
//label//span[text()='Apple']//following-sibling::span[text()='56']//parent::label
```

or

```
//label//span[@class='‘name’' and text()='Apple']//following-sibling::span[@class='‘price’' and text()='23']//parent::label
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
 <p class="intro">23</p>
 <p class="intro">11</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p class="intro">27</p>
 <p class="intro">11</p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const x = document.getElementsByClassName("intro");
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
 if(x[i].innerHTML == "23"){
  var obj = x[i].parentElement;
 }
}
obj.style.backgroundColor  = "red";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).